# Как удалить несколько элементов сразу из массива?

Tags: python, list

Я писал алгоритм для одной работы, и столкнулся с одной проблемой: А как удалить несколько элементов сразу с массива?
Например есть такой код:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,5]
a.remove(*b)
```

этот код не работает (выдает ошибку, что `.remove()` должен получить только один элемент).

Есть и еще такой код:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,5]
for i in b:
    a.remove(i)
```

Но проблема этого кода в том, что он медленный (и `a`, и `b` имеют более 1000 элементов).

Есть ли алгоритмы (или команды), которые смогут решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Встроенный тип `set` (множество) поддерживает операцию вычитания (`-`):

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,5]

print(list(set(a) - set(b)))
```

Вывод:

```
[2, 4]
```

Comment: А никто даже не подумал нормально протестировать данный код. Он не работает, например: `a = [1,2,3,3,1,2]` и `b = [1,2,3]`, что разве в результате должен быть пустой список??

Comment: @чистов_n Я проверял код, это либо неверно что-то написали, либо проблема в версии python

Comment: @Master'sTime а что должно по вашему мнению получиться при `a = [1,2,3,3,1,2]` и `b = [1,2,3]`? Не важно каким алгоритмом, просто при условиях вопроса.

Comment: @Master'sTime ваш код единственный правильный, просто он медленный, он в результате выдаёт `[3, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 6):

Порядок элементов в `a` сохраняется. Дополнительная память - `b_set` и копия `a`. Сложность линейная.

```
b_set = set(b)
a[:] = (x for x in a if x not in b_set)
```

**P.S.** В первой версии ответа я рассчитывал, что предыдущий код не создаёт копию списка `a` - справа генератор, дополнительная память для него не нужна. Но проверка исходного кода Питона открыла истину: если слева срез, а справа генератор, из этого генератора создают список, который потом копируется в срез. Особенность реализации - срезы работают с коллекциями, которые "знают" свою длину. Генераторы так не умеют, поэтому их копируют.

Как бы то ни было, список `a` копируется. А хочется обойтись без этой копии. Старый добрый алгоритм с двумя указателями:

```
b_set = set(b)

j = 0
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x not in b_set:
        a[j] = a[i]
        j += 1
del a[j:]
```

Answer (score 3):

С помощью [разности множеств](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/mnozhestva-v-python#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,3,5]

a = list(set(a) - set(b))

print(a)
```

Comment: То же самое )))

Comment: Я просто решил голосовать за самый быстрый ответ

Comment: Верный ответ дал самому первому, но голос отдал обоим чтобы без обид

Comment: `a[:] = set(a) - set(b)`.

Comment: ахах, спасибо, на одну операцию быстрее)

Comment: @Master'sTime, да нет не быстрее. Я почитал исходники Питона. `a[:] = ...` создаёт список из правого выражения, если там исходно не список получался. Время одно и то же.